# Why does pandas.apply return an index on the first iteration instead of the actual element?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

### Current Problem:

I currently have the following pandas dataframe object:

```
>>> print(my_df)
                        Date   Revenue
0  2023-12-27 00:00:00-05:00   3880359
1  2023-12-26 00:00:00-05:00   3139100
2  2023-12-22 00:00:00-05:00   2849700
3  2023-12-21 00:00:00-05:00   4884800
4  2023-12-20 00:00:00-05:00   4032200
5  2023-12-19 00:00:00-05:00   4979100
6  2023-12-18 00:00:00-05:00   6314700
7  2023-12-15 00:00:00-05:00  11503000
8  2023-12-14 00:00:00-05:00   8033300
9  2023-12-13 00:00:00-05:00   7727900
```

I get normal expected results when I loop through `Revenue` column:

```
>>> my_df['Revenue'].apply(lambda x: print(x, type(x)))
3880359 <class 'int'>
3139100 <class 'int'>
2849700 <class 'int'>
4884800 <class 'int'>
4032200 <class 'int'>
4979100 <class 'int'>
6314700 <class 'int'>
11503000 <class 'int'>
8033300 <class 'int'>
7727900 <class 'int'>
```

I get abnormal unexpected results when I loop through `Date` column:

```
>>> my_df['Date'].apply(lambda x: print(x, type(x)))
DatetimeIndex(['2023-12-27 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-26 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-22 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-21 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-20 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-19 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-18 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-15 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-14 00:00:00-05:00', '2023-12-13 00:00:00-05:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', freq=None) <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
2023-12-27 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-26 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-22 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-21 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-20 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-19 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-18 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-15 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-14 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2023-12-13 00:00:00-05:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

**Why is this happening? Why do I get an index object at first?**

### Steps to Reproduce:

Create a file locally named `example.json` with the following contents:

```
{"Date":{"0":1703653200000,"1":1703566800000,"2":1703221200000,"3":1703134800000,"4":1703048400000,"5":1702962000000,"6":1702875600000,"7":1702616400000,"8":1702530000000,"9":1702443600000},"Revenue":{"0":3880359,"1":3139100,"2":2849700,"3":4884800,"4":4032200,"5":4979100,"6":6314700,"7":11503000,"8":8033300,"9":7727900}}
```

Create a file locally named `example.py` with the following contents:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming "example.json" is in the same directory as your Python script or notebook
file_path = 'example.json'

# Read DataFrame from JSON file
df = pd.read_json(file_path)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

# Recreate the problem
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: print(x, type(x)))
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce (`pandas == 2.1.4`). Which version are you using?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Using `pandas == 1.5.2`, will upgrade now to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Issue still exists for versions `pandas-2.0.3`, `python-dateutil-2.8.2`, `tzdata-2023.3`. Currently trying to post example dataframe init code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate this error without revealing sensitive sections of the codebase.

The provided re-serialized JSON example fails to highlight the issue, suggesting a potential obscure bug within the library codebase (perhaps interim cached variables). If my assumption is accurate, finding a practical solution to the problem is unlikely. I resolved the issue by implementing the following (hacky) straightforward fix.

### Instead of doing this:

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: print(x, type(x)))
```

### I am simply doing this:

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: print(x, type(x)) if not isinstance(x, pd.DatetimeIndex) else None)
```